# Check is not defined on express-validator using routes V4

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

I've been developing an app with expressjs, but came with an error while using express-validator V4. The error is:
`TypeError: check is not a function`

So my code looks like this:

```
//users.js
var check  = require('express-validator/check');
var validationResult = require('express-validator/check');

router.post('/register',[
    check('name').exists()
], function(req, res){
    var errors = validationResult(req);
    if(errors){
        console.log('There are errors');
    }else{
        console.log('No errors');
    };
});

module.exports = function(app){
    app.use('/users', router);
};
```

Note that I am using pure javascript, no ES6.
Thanks.

Comment: Your node version ??

Comment: For node is v8.4.0.

Comment: Just for the record, ES6 **is** pure JavaScript. With Node 8, you can use all of its features without a transpiler like Babel, so what's holding you back?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

express-validator embraces ES6, and it supports Node 6+.
As you stated in the comments, you're using Node 8.4.0, then you're good with it.

You're importing the functions wrong, as you must bind the functions from the default export. Or use destructuring, which is a lot cooler:

```
const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator/check');

// or:

const check = require('express-validator/check').check;
const validationResult = require('express-validator/check').validationResult;
```

<sub>Also, remember to check the [usage section](https://github.com/ctavan/express-validator#usage) :)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the '/check' part from your require statement to have

```
var check  = require('express-validator');
var validationResult = require('express-validator');
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax of `app.use(expressValidator())` is the **legacy syntax** of express-validator.  See https://express-validator.github.io/docs/legacy-api.html for details.

It's recommended that you upgrade your code and syntax to the newer version, where `check` is a middleware on its own ([example](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/)), instead of a member function of `req`.

However, if you don't want to rewrite the whole validator part of your code, then all you need to do is in your `package.json` make the version of express-validator to be `express-validator:~3` (instead of `^6...` of whatever that is) and do `npm i`.  That should fix it.