# express-validator not initializing properly in express 4

Tags: node.js, express, express-validator

When starting express-validator 6.3 with Express 4 and Node.js 11 like this:

```
var express = require('express');

const { check, validationResult } = require('express-validator');

var app = express()

app.use(express.json())

app.post('/whatever', [
      check('somevariable').escape() // <---keeps saying that check is not defined!? same error if I change "check" to "sanitize"
    ], (req, res) => {
      console.log(req.body.somevariable);
})
```

I keep getting a ReferenceError: check is not defined. What am I doing wrong!?

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46515854/check-is-not-defined-on-express-validator-using-routes-v4

Answer (score 0):

For `"express-validator": "^6.5.0"`, It should be:

```js
const express = require('express');
const { check } = require('express-validator');
const app = express();
const port = 3000;
app.use(express.json());
app.post('/whatever', [check('somevariable').escape()], (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body.somevariable);
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log(`server listen port ${port}`));
```

NOT:

```
const check = require('express-validator');
```

See [Getting Started](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/) for `express-validator` module

Comment: Hm, still the same error. Updated my question with your code.